# Pointing to an element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Below is the cluttered version of my code that shows only the basic structure.
I'm just trying to use a pointer to an element of an array in a function but
I constantly get

```
C:\Users\whale\Desktop\20_Pay2.cpp:4:45: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'money'
```

but I still have no clue what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void pay_amount (int *dollars, int k, int *money[k]);

int main(void)
{
    int dollars=180, i=1, a[4]={20,10,5,1};
    pay_amount (&dollars, i, &a[i] );

    return 0;
}

void pay_amount (int *dollars, int k, int *money[k])
{
    printf("functions");
}
```

Comment: this code compiles. pls provide MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: How far did you get in your troubleshooting efforts using the debugger?

Comment: @CIsForCookies It shouldn't, the third argument to `pay_amount` is the wrong type

Comment: @ray A debugger doesn't help with compiler errors.

Comment: @ray a debugger is not used for fixing compilation errors

Comment: gcc 5.3.0 only displays warning, no errors

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: @M.M I get only a warning about that -> _warning: passing argument 3 of 'pay_amount' from incompatible pointer_

Comment: The one I posted was the full sentence.

Comment: Okay seeing the downvotes, I probably did something wrong. Sorry it is my first time posting and I'm too elementary to understand the meaning of debugger. I use Dev C++.

Comment: C++ does not support VLAs, which you are coding here `void pay_amount (int *dollars, int k, int *money[k])`. `money` is taken as a VLA with `k` elements, `k` pointers to `int`, BTW.

Comment: @PuffedRiceCracker A full error message should include the error location, i.e. the filename and line number.

Comment: Ahh, I've got the same message on line 4 and 15, and col (I don't know what it is) is 45. File is " C:\Users\whale\Desktop\20_Pay2.cpp". Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene True. I had the usual MCVE request in mind, since ClsForCookies said the code had compiled. Honest mixup.

Comment: @PuffedRiceCracker OK, that makes slightly more sense. You're using C++, not C.

Comment: @CIsForCookies unfortunately some compilers say "warning" for errors in their default mode

Comment: @PuffedRiceCracker "col" is the column of the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. But did I miss something that every post should include? I thought this post is okay because I stated my purpose and excluded irrelevant parts. (yeah I made mistakes but that was out of ignorance.) Is it because I asked something too basic?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parameter list you're using (`int k, int *money[k]`) is not valid C++ syntax. Unfortunately g++ produces a less than helpful message for this.

The good news is that you don't want this anyway: It would declare `money` to be an array of `k` pointers to `int`. What you actually want is just a pointer to `int`:

```
void pay_amount(int *dollars, int k, int *money);
```

`a` is an array of `int`, `a[i]` is a single `int`, so `&a[i]` is a pointer to an int, `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
pay_amount (&dollars, i, &a[i] );
```

The third parameter you pass is a pointer to a integer.
But in your function declaration, you have that :

```
void pay_amount (int *dollars, int k, int *money[k]);
```

`int *money[k]` as a function parameter does not seems correct.

You may want to do that :

```
void pay_amount (int *dollars, int k, int *money);
```

Here, money is a pointer to an integer